# Text doesnt wrap inside div and word-break is not working

Tags: html, css, word-wrap, word-break

I have a div with a width of 10%, but the text inside it doesn't wrap in the div. I already read some solutions with the CSS `word-break: break-all;` or `word-wrap:break-word;`.

But unfortunately it doesn't seem to work.

```css
.card {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  height: 75vh;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-top: 12.5vh;
}

.one {
  width: 20vw;
  word-break: break-all;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="card one">
  <p> a lot of text </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You need some corrections there.

You need to provide `width: 20vw` and `background-color` to card.

then `width:10%` to `p`.

Check out the snippet.

```css
.card {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  height: 75vh;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-top: 12.5vh;
  width: 20vw;
  background: red;
}

p {
  width: 10%; 
  word-break: break-all;

}
```

```html
<div class="card one">
  <p> a lot of text</p>
</div>
```